# How to stop overflow of shadow out of parent div?

Tags: css

The shadow of the child div can be seen out of the parent divs boundaries. Is there any way to stop this shadow? Same with the child divs.

This is just a simple template of my page, at the time when the page is running i won't be able to control the position and the number of divs, so i need a generalized css/method where shadows of children div dont overlap and they dont overflow out of the parent when they are at the corner.

```
<div style="width:600px; height:700px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; background: #eaeaea;">
    <div style="height:50px;width:50px; background:#ff0000; box-shadow: #000 0px 0px 3px;"></div>
    <div style="height:50px;width:50px; background:#ff0000; box-shadow: #000 0px 0px 3px;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `overflow:hidden` to your parent `div`.

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/VLWd6/)

Comment: Awesome!
But what about the overlapping of the child divs??

Comment: in this case, you need to wrap your red `div`s within another container and transfer the `box-shadow` in this container. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/VLWd6/1/

Answer (score 4):

Add `overflow:hidden` to the parent `div`.

[**JSFiddle Link**](http://jsfiddle.net/fuSQa/)